# Does ParseControl do any caching?

Tags: asp.net, caching, user-controls, controls, parsecontrol

We use `Page.ParseControl` to interpret a string of XML into controls. Does it use some kind of caching mechanism? If not - is there a way to cache its result?

`Page.LoadControl` seems to support some sort of caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any caching involved.
As a `Control` is a reference types, caching wouldn't be recommended in this case. (You want a new instance of the control each time you call the `ParseControl` function)

Comment: True. But the LoadControl performs caching.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadControl` doesn't perform caching per say, but the difference is rather that `ParseControl` will parse the input string every time to create the control dynamically, while `LoadControl` will re-use the parsed control template and class type when creating new instances, making it an order of magnitude faster.